# How to access the index of a particular item in GridView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using GridView.builder which contains 25 items and I want to GestureDetector on starting item. How will I  be able to access that item?

This is something I get to know :

```
 int x, y = 0;
  x = (index / gridStateLength).floor();
  y = (index % gridStateLength);
```

Here is the code which contains 25 items and I want to access the one

```
class Grid4 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 25,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white70, shape: BoxShape.circle)),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 40,
            crossAxisSpacing: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about adding a GestureDetector to every item and calling a function with the index as parameter. (Code written here in the browser :-) )

```
class Grid4 extends StatelessWidget {
  void tapped(int index){
    if(index == 1){
      print("huray 1");
    } else {
      print("not the one :(");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 25,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => tapped(index),
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white70, shape: BoxShape.circle))),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 40,
            crossAxisSpacing: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks thats so easy and what if I want to add an image in OnTappin at index one?

Comment: one possible answer is that you do the same: Calling a function with the parameter index which returns a (Image)Widget or an empty Widget